# An exemple of strict inequality for reverse inequality Minkowski for space $L^p$, $0 < p <1$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let  be $0<p<1$. Suppose that we know that 
$$ \bigg(\int (u + v)^p\bigg)^{1/p} \geq \bigg(\int (u)^p\bigg)^{1/p} +\bigg(\int (v)^p\bigg)^{1/p}$$
for all $u,v \geq 0$ in $L^p$. I need find an exemple of functions how $u$ and $v$ such that the inequality above is strict.

Comment: You really need to try.

Comment: You need some hipothesis about $u$ and $v$. For details, see https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/352_05_JIPAM/352_05_www.pdf

Comment: My case is different, I need $0 < p <1$. Your case is  with  $p >1$.

Comment: A good way to do something like this is to go through the proof and find the step(s) that produce a "$\geq$" and find $u,v$ that make each of them an equality.

Answer (score 1):

Standard answer: Take any $u=v\in L^p$ (ie. almost everywhere). Equality is obvious. A bit more generally, you can take $u=cv$ a.e. where $c$ is a constant.

You can get here, as I mentioned in my comment, by observing that the inequality ultimately comes from the concavity of $\log$, and that inequality is an equality exactly when the two points on the graph that you're looking at are the same.